# 07 3.8l Chrysler Town and Country Stalls when accelerating

Tags: stall, chrysler, town-and-country

I'm looking at purchasing a Mini van  that has pretty good mileage on it. Only 80k but has the issue I described in the title.  The codes read "Mass airflow sensor, Throttle body Position sensor". the current owner has replaced  the throttle body position sensor, Crankshaft position Sensor, Fuse box, and computer but is still having the issue. I'm thinkin that if this can be fixed its likely going to be a very long lasting vehicle. Does anyone have any thoughts on what the issue might be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure on the T&C, but quite a few vehicles have a "relearn" procedure which needs to be done when replacing the TPS. What you're describing certainly sounds like a TPS sensor issue.

Comment: A faulty MAF sensor can cause this also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a host of problems that can be wrong with this, especially now that the computer has been changed. It is probably going to be a fault or faults in one or more circuits. I have very good experience with this generation of T&C. If there's little to no rust problems I would take it somewhere that's good at electrical diagnostics and pay for a prepurchase inspection. This should make your decision much easier.